# black background when overriding drawRect in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I am trying to override drawRect in my UIScrolLView, however it gives me this black background instead of the background color that I've specified for my UIScrollView. Why is this? If I remove the drawRect code then everything is fine:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if (shouldDrawVerticalLineForProfile){

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGColorRef separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:47.0/255.0 
                                                     blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

        // Add at bottom
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(60, 0);
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(60, 10000);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, separatorColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);  

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the backgroundColor property simply wraps a CGContextAddRect and CGContextFillPath, what if you do something like that?

Comment: drawing the bgcolor manually using the two functions I mentioned above.

Comment: I know that this doesn't fundamentally solve the problem, but I just ended up moving my custom logic from `override func draw(rect: CGRect)` method to `override func layoutSubviews()`. But it worked specifically in my case.

Answer (score 23):

I guess what you are searching for is:

```
myScrollViewInstance.opaque = NO
```

After that the background of your scroll view should not be black anymore.

Comment: I tried this but didn't help. I think it is not that the background is black. Only when scrollView's drawRect is override, the scrollView becomes black. If drawRect is not overridden, the scrollview is white as normal.

Comment: This answer is only correct in the event that you actually want a semi-transparent background. It will fail if you expect a non-clear `backgroundColor` to be respected.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar situation when overriding drawRect in my UIScrollView subclass.

Simply overriding with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

resulted in a black background instead of the desired clear background I'd get without overriding.

I found it was because the View Background was set to Default in Interface Builder and that setting it to `Clear Color` resolved the issue for me.

I'm not sure if this is related to your problem but thought I'd share in case it might help.

Comment: UIView's `drawRect:` is documented as "The default implementation of this method does nothing.", so calling it certainly will not do anything. You have to fill the background yourself.

Answer (score 10):

The answer here is very clearly documented in the AppleDocs for UIView's `drawRect:` method. The first sentence is:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing.

So, the suggestions here to call super are not going to help. The rest of the answer is contained further down in the discussion:

> ... if the opaque property of your view is set to YES, your drawRect: method must totally fill the specified rectangle with opaque content.

Meaning that if you don't intend to have a transparent background, you need to actually draw the background. The most correct way to do this is to use the following `drawRect:` template:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect]; // optional if a direct UIView-subclass, should be called otherwise.

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Fill the background color, if needed
    if (self.opaque) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }

    // Your code here...
}
```

**Swift Update**

Since you are responsible to add background color on your custom view, make sure to fill rect with color:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
   super.draw(rect)
   guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    context.saveGState()
    // Add you custom color
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)
    defer { context.restoreGState() }
    
    // Your custom drawing ....

}
```

**By the way, you could also set your custom view background color on `init`. Then you do not need to fill rect with color as stated above.**

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: Absolutely working answer. Great explanation Adam

Comment: Happy to help. Maybe this is the decade where my answer finally gets the 15 additional votes to be at the top :)

Answer (score 4):

This should help

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, colorBack);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

// Choose bounds and  colorBack accordingly

Comment: Use rect, not bounds to allow UIKit to optimize drawing when needed.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this its Work for me

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
            [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        [super drawRect:rect];
        if (shouldDrawVerticalLineForProfile){

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGColorRef separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:47.0/255.0 
                                                         blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

            // Add at bottom
            CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(60, 0);
            CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(60, 10000);

            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, separatorColor);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);  

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me was to explicitly set the background after any call to `setNeedsDisplay`. In my example, I was using a subclass of an `MKAnnotationView` over a map, instead of a `UIScrollView`, so I don't *really* know how well this applies to the OP scenario. In my case, I was calling `setNeedsDisplay` from `setAnnotation`, and I found that doing so resets by `backgroundColor`. Simply re-setting by `backgroundColor` after `setNeedsDisplay` fixes the problem.

FWIW, I too observed that simply overriding `drawRect` to delegate to the super class caused this black background problem.