# Line before and after text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I would like to achieve the same result as this :

[image]

I already saw this : [Draw line in UILabel before and after text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291121/draw-line-in-uilabel-before-and-after-text) , but I would like to know if there's a way to do this with only one UILabel ?

Comment: subclass `UIView` and perform manual drawing depends on text. Using `UIBezierPath` is simplest way. This is not hard, but takes some time; also it is pretty interesting coding as I think

Comment: Can you show an example ? :)

Comment: I can share my code for customized `UITextField`, that have underline for full width

Comment: This would be great :)

Comment: I am bored so you may check my solution for exactly your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is custom view as you requested

```
import UIKit

class CustomizedUILabel: UIView
{
    let label = UILabel()
    var lineInsideOffset: CGFloat = 20
    var lineOutsideOffset: CGFloat = 4
    var lineHeight: CGFloat = 1
    var lineColor = UIColor.grayColor()

//MARK: - init
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initLabel()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initLabel()
    }
    convenience init() {self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)}
    func initLabel()
    {
        label.textAlignment = .Center

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bot = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let lead = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: label, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trail = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: label, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        addSubview(label)
        addConstraints([top, bot, lead, trail, centerX])

        //... if the opaque property of your view is set to YES, your drawRect: method must totally fill the specified rectangle with opaque content.
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318987/black-background-when-overriding-drawrect-in-uiscrollview
        opaque = false
    }

//MARK: - drawing
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let lineWidth = label.frame.minX - rect.minX - lineInsideOffset - lineOutsideOffset
        if lineWidth <= 0 {return}

        let lineLeft = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(rect.minX + lineOutsideOffset, rect.midY, lineWidth, 1))
        let lineRight = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(label.frame.maxX + lineInsideOffset, rect.midY, lineWidth, 1))

        lineLeft.lineWidth = lineHeight
        lineColor.set()
        lineLeft.stroke()

        lineRight.lineWidth = lineHeight
        lineColor.set()
        lineRight.stroke()
    }
}
```

Usage in code: in usual case you should provide top, leading and trailing/width constraints and let `CustomizedUILabel` to determine height by its internal `UILabel`. Lets show our label in debug mode in some view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customizedLabel = CustomizedUILabel()
    customizedLabel.label.text = "RATE YOUR RIDE"
    customizedLabel.label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    customizedLabel.label.font = customizedLabel.label.font.fontWithSize(25)
    customizedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(customizedLabel)

    customizedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: customizedLabel, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: -100)
    let trail = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: customizedLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let lead = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: customizedLabel, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([top, trail, lead])
}
```

Usage in xib/storyboard: as soon as you implemented init with coder initializer you can use this view in xib/storyboard. You need add `UIView` element to your superview, assign Class for this element to `CustomizedUILabel`, perform constraints and make outlet. Then you can use it with pretty same way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var customizedLabel: CustomizedUILabel!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    customizedLabel.label.text = "RATE YOUR RIDE"
    customizedLabel.label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    customizedLabel.label.font = customizedLabel.label.font.fontWithSize(25)
    customizedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems great but I got an error : `fatal error: This class does not support NSCoding:` // I added my view in storyboard and not only in code .. Is that bad ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz you can easily adopt this code for using in xib/storyboard; check edited answer

Comment: Yes that's what I saw, sorry for the dumb comment ! Thank your very much for your code :)

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz no, not dumb comment, your comment was interesting. I edited my answer just right now, after your question

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,20);
label.text = @"Rate Your Ride";
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label sizeToFit];

float w = self.view.frame.size.width;
float lw = label.frame.size.width;
float offset = (w-lw)/2;
float padding = 20.0f;

//center the label
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 0, lw, 20)];

//make the borders
UIImageView * left = [UIImageView new];
left.frame = CGRectMake(0, 9, offset-padding, 2);
left.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:left];

UIImageView * right = [UIImageView new];
right.frame = CGRectMake(w-offset+padding, 9, offset-padding, 2);
right.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view right];
```

OR

make the label background the same colour as its parent and put a single line behind it.